# How to modify style hint without QProxyStyle?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyside, qstyle

I use Python bindings of Qt (PySide or PyQt4). They don't have `QProxyStyle`.

I want to change the value of a style hint. For example change the `SH_Menu_SubMenuPopupDelay` popup delay time of a submenu.

In native C++ Qt I would use a `QProxyStyle` and override `styleHint` and filter for the style hint of interest and return the value I like. It's done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24719739/how-to-use-qstylesh-tooltip-wakeupdelay-to-set-tooltip-wake-up-time) for example.

But in the Python bindings I use `QProxyStyle` is not available. So how can a style hint of an existing style be modified there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The menu popup delay is not a fixed value, as it will depend on the current style. There is no way to set it programmatically.

The Qt way to modify style hints for existing styles is via `QProxyStyle`. However, even that is not guaranteed to work for user-defined or third-party styles, because they are not obliged to call `QStyle.proxy()`. And even if they did, neither PyQt nor PySide wrap any classes that are based on plugins (which includes `QProxyStyle`).

The only way to get full control over the behaviour of style-hints is to write your own, application-specific style class. But, of course, you would then no longer be modifying the style-hints of an **existing** style, so that is beyond the scope of the current question.

That seems to leave one remaining option, which is to subclass `QMenu` and bypass the style-hint altogether. Grepping the Qt source code reveals that (disregarding the various style classes) the only places where `SH_Menu_SubMenuPopupDelay` is used is within the `mouseMoveEvent` of `QMenu`. So it might be possible to reimplement that to get the behaviour you want.

**UPDATE**:

The `QProxyStyle` class is now available in PyQt5.

Comment: I accept this answer because it convinced me that modifying style hints of an existing style is difficult to impossible. It's a pity however that they didn't make the style hints modifiable.