# qt set max height to a dropdown combobox (style cleanlooks)

Tags: python-2.7, qt, pyqt4

I'm working on a software which contains combobox with a lot of items inside, the problem is when I click on it the list is too large and I can't see all of the items by scrolling on it.

The style cleanlooks is used (that's why the combobox have a too large size) but I can't change it so I'm looking for a solution to set a maximum size.

I found nothing about this on the web, neither in the documentation.

I tried to use the size policy but doesn't work. I also tried to get the QLineEdit used by the combobox and to set a QSize on it and finally to by setting stylesheet on the combobox and on the QLineEdit but nothing worked properly.

What I tried with the QSize and the stylesheet :

```
sz = QSize(20, 20)
combo.view().setGridSize(sz)

combo.view().setStyleSheet("""QListView { max-height: 50px; background-color: yellow; } """)
combo.setStyleSheet("""QComboBox { max-height: 30px; background-color: pink; } """)
```

EDIT: After the comment of @Vladimir Bershov I tried to set correctly the size with : setMaxVisibleItems() but as said in the doc ("Note: This property is ignored for non-editable comboboxes in styles that returns true for QStyle::SH_ComboBox_Popup") the property is ignored.

So I looked for modify the QStyle Hint to unset the SH_ComboBox_Popup but as explained on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28233907/how-to-modify-style-hint-without-qproxystyle) that's impossible.

If you have any suggestions I'm listening.

Thanks.

Comment: Looks like you need [`setMaxCount()`](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qcombobox.html#setMaxCount) or [`setMaxVisibleItems()`](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qcombobox.html#setMaxVisibleItems)

Comment: I tried this but that's ignored, I have seen this in the doc : "Note: This property is ignored for non-editable comboboxes in styles that returns true for QStyle::SH_ComboBox_Popup such as the Mac style or the Gtk+ Style."  which may explain why. I tried by setting the combobox to Editable before and it works so I'm looking this way

Comment: @pipou. The `QProxyStyle` class is now available in PyQt5. I tried it with the Cleanlooks style, and overriding the style-hint for `SH_ComboBox_Popup` works. There is no way to fix this issue in PyQt4.

Comment: @ekhumoro thanks for the informations I will mark it as resolve even if there's no solution almost that's well explained.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like explained in the comments there's no available solutions in PyQt4

Answer (score 1):

This line worked for me when I was trying to minimize the height of the QComboBox dropdown in Qt/C++.

`ComboBox->setStyleSheet("combobox-popup: 0;");`

Comment: Please markup your code and provide more detail for further information.